# convert XML with repeating elements to SQL table

Tags: sql-server, xml

i have an xml with many rows  that i want to convert to a sql table. 
 the xml has repeating elements and i want to retrieve the data so every row in the table  will have all the column names (all field names in a row )  and their values .

"all the elements have the field name= " so i cant seem to separate each one of them into a different column and apply the value for it

- i have searched the web but could not find 
  something that works for this kind of xml

here is my XML

```
<resultset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<field name="id_report">1</field>

<field name="title_report" xsi:nil="true"/>

<field name="loan_taken_flag">1</field>

<field name="structured_text_flag">0</field>

</row>

<row>

<field name="id_report">2</field>

<field name="title_report" xsi:nil="true"/>

<field name="loan_taken_flag">0</field>

<field name="structured_text_flag">0</field>

</row>

</resultset>
```

the output should look like this

```
 id_report title_report  loan_taken_flag structured_text_flag
  1  NULL  1   0

  2  Null  0   0
```

this is what i have got to so far but i can only get the name of the element and the values to appear in 2 columns but i as i said i want a column for each element

```
DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM dbo.XMLwithOpenXML

DECLARE @handle INT  
DECLARE @PrepareXmlStatus nvarchar(max)

EXEC @PrepareXmlStatus= sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @XML  


 SELECT  FieldName,FieldValue
 FROM    OPENXML(@handle, '/resultset/row/field',2)
 WITH (


        FieldName  varchar(50) '@name',
       FieldValue varchar(500) '.'       
   )

 EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

Comment: Is that a `XML` sample. Please Edit your question with proper sample data and expected output also what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**Nodes Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188282.aspx) to extract data from `Xml` Type

> The nodes() method is useful when you want to shred an xml data type
>   instance into relational data. It allows you to identify nodes that
>   will be mapped into a new row.

Try something like this.

```
DECLARE @XML XML

SELECT @XML = '<resultset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
<field name="id_report">1</field>
<field name="title_report" xsi:nil="true"/>
<field name="loan_taken_flag">1</field>
<field name="structured_text_flag">0</field>
</row>
<row>
<field name="id_report">2</field>
<field name="title_report" xsi:nil="true"/>
<field name="loan_taken_flag">0</field>
<field name="structured_text_flag">0</field>
</row>
</resultset>'

SELECT id_report = [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(field)[1]', 'int'),
       title_report= [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value('(field)[2]', 'varchar(50)'),
       loan_taken_flag = [Xml_Tab].[Cols].value(' (field)[3]', 'Bit'),
       structured_text_flag=[Xml_Tab].[Cols].value(' (field)[4]', 'Bit')
FROM   @XML.nodes('/resultset/row') AS [Xml_Tab]([Cols])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use nodes() to shred on `/resultset/row` and use a predicate in the values function on `@name` to extract the value for each column.

```sql
declare @XML xml = '
<resultset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <row>
    <field name="id_report">1</field>
    <field name="title_report" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <field name="loan_taken_flag">1</field>
    <field name="structured_text_flag">0</field>
  </row>
  <row>
    <field name="id_report">2</field>
    <field name="title_report" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <field name="loan_taken_flag">0</field>
    <field name="structured_text_flag">0</field>
  </row>
</resultset>'

select T.X.value('(field[@name = "id_report"]/text())[1]', 'int') as id_report,
       T.X.value('(field[@name = "title_report"]/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') as title_report,
       T.X.value('(field[@name = "loan_taken_flag"]/text())[1]', 'bit') as loan_taken_flag,
       T.X.value('(field[@name = "structured_text_flag"]/text())[1]', 'bit') as structured_text_flag
from @XML.nodes('/resultset/row') as T(X)
```

Result:

```
id_report   title_report loan_taken_flag structured_text_flag
----------- ------------ --------------- --------------------
1           NULL         1               0
2           NULL         0               0
```